# Liferay: multiple language support for blog

Tags: liferay, blogs, localized

I am using Liferay 6.0 EE and trying out the blog portlet. I noticed the content of the classic Web Content Display can be localized, but I can't find how to have the same functionality for blog. Is there any way to have localized blog?

[image: Web Content Display]

[image: Blog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Nien, Nada... Blog has no multi language support.

You can use category to mark different blog post for different language.

Create a page for every language, use asset publisher portlet that show blog post targeting language by category.